# Confused about multilingual collation in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, multilingual, collation

Just when I thought I understood multilingual collation in Perl...

I'm getting what appears to be different results for the relative ordering of $ and %
when I use Unicode collation, compared to when I use plain old "cmp". I don't think my 
Unicode result is correct.

The following script outputs:

```
Vanilla collation: alpha CMP beta for  is -1      # I get it: "alpha" comes before "beta"
Unicode::Collate collation: alpha CMP beta is -1  # I get it: "alpha" comes before "beta"
Vanilla collation: $ CMP % for  is -1             # I get it $ comes before %
Unicode::Collate collation: $ CMP % is 1          # So why is this result different?
```

### So that's my question: Why does Unicode collation think that % comes before $ ?

```
use HTML::Entities;
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;

require 'Unicode/Collate/Locale/fr.pl';


my $COLL = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(
    locale => "fr",
                     );

{
my $a_text = "alpha";
my $b_text = "beta";


my $result = $a_text cmp $b_text;    # returns 1, 0, or -1.
printf qq(Vanilla collation: %s CMP %s for $lang is %s\n), $a_text, $b_text, $result;

my $result1 = $COLL->cmp( $a_text, $b_text );    # returns 1, 0, or -1.
printf qq(Unicode::Collate collation: %s CMP %s is %s\n), $a_text, $b_text, $result1;
}

{
my $a_text = "\$";
my $b_text = "%";


my $result = $a_text cmp $b_text;    # returns 1, 0, or -1.
printf qq(Vanilla collation: %s CMP %s for $lang is %s\n), $a_text, $b_text, $result;

my $result1 = $COLL->cmp( $a_text, $b_text );    # returns 1, 0, or -1.
printf qq(Unicode::Collate collation: %s CMP %s is %s\n), $a_text, $b_text, $result1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are correct.

The [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) defines how things are ordered, with the help of the [mappings](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt) which include the following:

```
0024  ; [.15BA.0020.0002] # DOLLAR SIGN
0025  ; [*037A.0020.0002] # PERCENT SIGN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. The ASCII code for DOLLAR sign is 36 and the ASCII code for % is 37.  So I have to conclude that ASCII sorting of these two characters differs from Unicode sorting. I had assumed they wouldn't contradict each other.

Comment: ASCII doesn't define a sorting order.